# Getting AngularJS html5api for pretty Urls working with NGINX and some custom php configuration

Tags: angularjs, nginx

I have a website that has affiliate urls which need to be accessed from both a subdomain and a directory. For Example:

```
http://someaffiliate.example.com
http://www.example.com/someaffiliate
```

To get this to work I have configured NGINX to check if a file or directory exists if not it forwards to a php page which gathers some affiliate data by using $uri then forwards to the subdomain URL.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html/app/;
    index index.html index.htm;

    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html /index.php?q=$uri;
    }
}
```

This has worked fine, the problem is this site is now a SPA running on AngularJS. I need to use the HTML5 Api so links can be pretty. If for example an affiliate wants to uses the URL:

```
http://someaffiliate.example.com/products
```

Rather than

```
http://someaffiliate.example.com/#/products
```

This doesn't work, because NGIX intercepts before it gets to Angular routes it to my php script which forwards it to:

```
http://products.example.com
```

Also links in my angular app get the same treatment. So basically the whole thing is broken.

Any ideas on how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

I do not have much experience with ngix but have you remembered to set the base url in your index.html? I know that is a common problem when setting up routing.

```
<base href="/">
```

See an example of this here:
http://andredublin.github.io/blog/2014/08/18/nginx-and-angularjs-url-routing/

Comment: Yes, I have that. The problem really isn't the routing, or even the nginx configuration, just in a conflict between the two. I need a third option on how to get this to work, and I have no idea what that could be.